If two twlever shia imams differ regarding a verdict does it prove they are fallible?

I asked Abu ‘Abdullah (Imam Jafar) regarding a woman who marries even though she has a husband who done zihar[14] upon her and he answered, “The woman will be stoned and the man will be lashed one hundred times, since he did not enquire.”

Shu’ayb says, “Thereafter, I went to Abu al Hassan (Imam al Kazim) and asked him, “What is the law regarding a woman who marries despite having a husband?”
He replied, “The woman will be stoned and there will be no action against the man.”
Later, I met Abu Basir and told him, “I asked Abu al Hassan regarding a woman who marries despite having a husband and he replied, ‘The woman will be stoned and there will be no action against the man.’”
Abu Basir responded by wiping his hand on his chest and saying, “I do not think that the intelligence of our Companion (the illustrious Imam) has reached its climax!”
Rijal al Kashshi, pg. 171-172, # 292
